# How to get json data array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I attach here my code please tell me how can i fetch value from this **json**.
for e.g. i want to get value of `pms_pro_amt` so this will give result 54.
This is my **json** response

```
    {"obj1": "{u'pms_pro_amt': '54', u'pms_client_cmpname': 'Tata Steels', u'pms_pro_priority': 'medium'
, u'pms_user_master_id': 0, u'pms_client_unique_id': 'c2', u'pms_pro_assign_id': '9', u'pms_pro_start_date'
: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0), u'pms_pro_status': 0, u'pms_category_id': 0, u'pms_pro_end_date'
: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 2, 0, 0), u'pms_pro_desc': 'jhk', u'pms_client_name': 'Ratan Tata', u'pms_pro_id'
: 1, u'pms_pro_attachment': '', u'pms_pro_timespend': '', u'pms_pro_amt_type': 'hourly', u'pms_pro_name'
: 'hj', u'pms_pro_tech': 'Java', u'pms_client_master_id': '2'}", "obj2": "[{u'pms_dev_name': 'gaTes'
}]"}
```

now i want to set first value to my textbox.This is my jquery code

```
 var id=$(this).attr("id");
    formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('id',id);
    $.ajax({
        url : '/view-project',
        data : formdata,
        type : 'post',
        contentType : false,
        cache : false,
        processData : false,
        success:function(data){
            if (data == 0){
                alert('No data Found');
            }
            else {

                $("#view_pro_client_cmpname").val(data['obj1']);
              }
```

I'm getting full **json** response in data variable. Now how to get only one key-value from this Response please help

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your JSON is invalid. But you can get your values like that.

```js
var data = {
  obj1: {
   param1: 'hey',
        param2: 'you'
  },
  obj2: {
   param1: 'is'
  }
}

//Show data like this
alert( data['obj1']['param1'] );
// Or like this
alert(data.obj1.param1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(key,value){
    alert(value.obj1);
});
```